# Attempting to setStringValue with NSLog formatting

Tags: objective-c

Im new to objective-c. I'm trying to make a calculator application. When I run this code:

```
-(void) addNums: (int)fnum: (int)snum {
    ans = fnum + snum;
    [result setStringValue:@"%i",ans];
}
```

to try and set the result label I get the error 
"Too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 2". I was expecting this to work the same way as `NSLog` formatting.

Thanks for the help. 
Let me know if you need to see more of my code.

Comment: `[result setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", ans]];` have a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html at the `+ stringWithFormat:`

Comment: @Popeye, you should probably make this an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @RobNapier I was busy at the time so it was quicker to just add a short comment, but I will add it now as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is use the `NSString` method `+ stringWithFormat:` so all you need to do is

```
[result setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ans]];
```

for a better understanding of `NSString` and the method `+ stringWithFormat:` please see the [Apple Documentation on NSString.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

I also noted that your whole method doesn't make sense. Please try the following

```
- (void)addNum:(int)fnum withNum:(int)snum {
    int ans = fnum + snum;
    [result setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ans]];
}
```

What was missing

1)  You had `-(void) addNums: (int)fnum: (int)snum` it should be `- (void)addNum:(int)fnum withNum:(int)snum`. Have a look at [Learning Objective-c A Primar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/) and have a look at the section titled `Methods and Messages` This will show you how to declare methods correctly.

2) You hadn't declared `ans` so instead of `ans = fnum + snum` it should be `int ans = fnum + snum;`

3) And finally you refer to `result` as a `UILabel` because of this `setStringValue:` is not a real method for `UILabel` it should be `setText:` so this line should be `[result setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ans]];` Alternatively you can do `result.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ans];` Check out [Apple documentation on UILabel](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html).